# How to find the parent collection to a document in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm searching a subquery in Firebase and I'm trying to find the parent collection (and then the parent document) it is a part of. Here is my code

```
let queryRef = orgRef.where('User_ID', '==', userID).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
          return;
        }  



        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.parent());
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

however using doc.parent, or snapshot.parent doesn't work. How do I find the parent documents of the subcollection?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a DocumentSnapshot object, you will want to use its `ref` property to get a [DocumentReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) object that points to it.  DocumentReference has a `parent` property that will get you the collection where the document lives.  So, you will probably want:

```
doc.ref.parent
```

For any given `doc` in the query results.